# Checking out a remote git branch that does not exist locally?

Tags: git, branch

Let's say there is a remote clone of the same git repository that my local repository is cloned from - and there is a branch on that remote clone that isn't present in my clone (not the default branch).

Is there a way to clone that remote branch into my local copy? I don't want to merge it with the current branch or anything like that. I just want to start a local copy of the remote branch. Is there a way to do this?

I would also like to know (once this is done) how to add the mentioned branch also to the default remote-copy that my local clone checks in with by default.

Answer (score 7):

You're going to want to run the following:

```
# Fetch everything from the other remote
git fetch <remote name>
# Check out the remote version of the branch
git checkout <remote name>/<branch name>
# Create the new local branch
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

That gives you a local, workable copy of your branch. Then, to push it back to the original remote (assuming it is `origin`), we just run

```
git push origin <branch name>:<branch name>
```

This will push your new branch up to your original remote.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. There is something I don't understand in your instructions. If you look at this pastebin http://pastebin.com/kujnaY9e maybe you can tell me what I am doing wrong, what I am misunderstanding in your suggestion.

Comment: Ah yes okay. Use `git remote add <name> <url>` first, then fetch using the remote name you provided. This way you can fetch later changes from that repository easily later as well. If you don't want to do this, `git fetch <remote> <branch>` and then `git checkout FETCH_HEAD` should do what you want, but you need to know what the name of the branch on the other remote is.

Answer (score 4):

One command will do this work:

```
git checkout -b <local_branch_name> origin/<remote_branch_name>
```

Edit:
If an error occurred:
fatal: 'origin/<branch_name>' is not a commit and a branch '<branch_name>' cannot be created from it.

You may try:

```
git pull
git checkout -b <local_branch_name> origin/<remote_branch_name>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use next:

```
git fetch <remote repo name>
git checkout -b <local branch name> <remote repo name>/<remote branch name>
```

It was helpful in my case and this procedure is identical to automatically generated action through TortoiseGit on my Windows machine.

Comment: Is *git fetch* always required?

Comment: @KonradViltersten yes

Answer (score 0):

As of Git version 2.37.2 you can now use `$ git switch -c` as shown in the steps below.

##### Fetch everything from the remote repository.

`$ git fetch <remote>`

##### Checkout the remote branch

`$ git checkout <remote>/<branch>`

##### Create the new local branch

`$ git switch -c <branch>`